# Symfony TWIG override block content of embedded twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some twigs that are embedded in base twig. Embedded twigs contain blocks that I'd like to override in other twigs, which extend base. This changes are not showing. I saw similar questions, but couldn't deduce the answer from that.

For example in base twig:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        {% embed 'Bundle::sidebar.html.twig' %}{% endembed %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Sidebar twig contains the block that should be overridden:

```
<div>Some content here</div>
{% block example_block %}
    Content of a block
{% endblock %}
```

Twig that extends the base:

```
{% extends 'Bundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block example_block %}
    I want different content here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: in the documentation they have really good examples, have you checked the manual? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Comment: Yes, I did. And I didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Docs on embed http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html I think this should work…

Base Twig Template:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    {% block sidebar %}
        {% embed 'Bundle::sidebar.html.twig' %}{% endembed %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Twig that extends base:

```
{% extends 'Bundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% embed "Bundle::sidebar.html.twig" %}
    {# This block is defined in "sidebar.html.twig" #}
    {# and we override it right here: #}
        {% block example_block %}
            I want different content here
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you declare a sidebar block in the base template, then override it in the extended file, declaring the embed again and the blocks you want to override.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was that I tried to use embed again, similar to your example, without wrapping it in block.